# How to pass data from the component to the main app in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I'm just curious about how to pass the data from the component to the main app. like, we pass the props to the component.

Comment: providing some codes would be easier to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Props can be only send to child components.

If you want to send data from child component to parent. It can be achieved by **emit**.

Read this article. You can understand it clearly.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/communication-between-components-using-emit-and-props-in-vue-js/